# Passing NULL as parameter in a where clause for a Snowflake function

Tags: function, null, parameter-passing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a function with parameters. If I pass null as the parameter in a where clause I would like it to bring back all results eg

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC(" CUSTCODE" VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE ("CUSTOMER_CODE" VARCHAR, CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '                                  
   SELECT  CUSTOMER_CODE, CUSTOMERNAME FROM DIM_CUSTOMER
    WHERE  CUSTOMER_CODE = CUSTCODE
';
```

So if CUSTCODE is NULL
then bring back all CUSTOMER_CODE
almost like ignoring the where clause

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Leon

Comment: "Could someone point me in the right direction?" - While I'm not familiar with Snowflake, I do know that SQL (ISO SQL and specific implementations) generally _does not allow for optional clauses_. While there are "tricks" like `FROM t WHERE @param IS NULL OR t.Column = @param`, they're invariably a bad idea because they mess-up the query-planner - which is why dynamic predicate conditions tend to be implemented with Dynamic SQL, which you cannot use in a `FUNCTION`  in every SQL implementation I've used. If Snowflake does specifically support and correctly handle it then I'll be surprised.

Comment: In case you are looking to build conditional SQL -  check usage of NVL2 function in snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dai's comment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DIM_CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_CODE text, CUSTOMERNAME text);

INSERT INTO DIM_CUSTOMER VALUES ('one', 'customer one'),('two', 'customer two');
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ABC(CUSTCODE VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (CUSTOMER_CODE VARCHAR, CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '                                  
   SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, CUSTOMERNAME FROM DIM_CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTCODE IS NULL OR CUSTOMER_CODE = CUSTCODE
';
```

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(ABC('one'));
```

gives:

| CUSTOMER_CODE | CUSTOMERNAME |
| --- | --- |
| one | customer one |

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(ABC(null::text));
```

gives:

| CUSTOMER_CODE | CUSTOMERNAME |
| --- | --- |
| one | customer one |
| two | customer two |

Comment: @SimeonePilgrim Hi Simeone I have another quick question if my function has multiple parameters say 7 of them and most are allowed NULLS whats the best way to handle it? ie we'll get different permutations of which parameters are  null.

Comment: Given it's a SQL Function, just make the inner SQL valid/work for each parameter, and handle them being null when they are null....

Comment: `
WHERE CUSTCODE IS NULL AND CUSTOMER_CODE = CUSTCODE AND CUSTPOSTCODE IS NULL
`

Comment: @Leon it would more likely need to be `WHERE (CUSTCODE IS NULL OR CUSTOMER_CODE = CUSTCODE) AND (CUSTPOSTCODE IS NULL OR CUSTPOSTCODE = CUSTPOSTCODE)` if you have many variable you are want to check.

Comment: which is the pattern `WHERE (column1_variable IS NULL OR column1 = column1_variable) AND (<repeat pattern for column 2-N>);`

Comment: Thanks Simeone I dont know how to thank you enough.

Comment: Hi Simeon ive added a parameter which allows an end user to specify their sort order
I've added that parameter as below to the function but it doesnt work - am i missing something? thaks in advance
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION X( "SORT" VARCHAR)
returns table blah blah
as 
select  * from table order by SORT

syntax error line 2 at position 3 unexpected 'SELECT'